# How to create a custom error controller or hook

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Basically I want to be able to know when a server error is served to the user. I saw that in earlier versions of Phoenix it was possible to define an `error_controller` in the config of your router but this feature is removed in the current version.

I also know of the ErrorView to be able to render your own errors, but I want to do some work that should not be done in the view (e.g sending notifications).

Is it possible to hook up your own controller in the current version of Phoenix, or are there other hooks or events that I can catch and use?

Comment: @TimPlegrim Errors are a special case inside Phoenix. Unless better opinion I would use `error_view.ex` for that as you can access there everything you need from the connection. You also have `error_helpers.ex`, inside the `views` folder.